# How can I disable mouse hover effect when user is using keyboard?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a search as you type feature on my site. I'm working on the front-end side right now and using mockjax to pull in fake data.

My problem: When the drop down menu pops up you have the option to go over your choices (which highlight in yellow). I realized today though that if your using the arrow keys to scroll through your choices and move your mouse over the menu then it will cause two options to be highlighted! I don't want to confuse my users so I only want it to highlight one at a time. If they are using their keyboard and hover over with the mouse than the keyboard selection would jump to where the mouse is.

(In case I'm not being clear and you need an example, go to amazon and use their search with your arrow keys and then hover the mouse over an option, it changes. I want it like that!)

Most of the html, css and mockjax can't be included in this fiddle so it looks funky- but just case someone needs to see my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/2JGHu/

```
(function (Backbone, _, context) {

"use strict";

var SuggestiveSearch = Backbone.View.extend({

    tracking: function (action, label) {

        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'SearchAsYouType2.0', action, label]);
    },

    fetchTemplate: function (name) {

        var callback = _.bind(function (template) {
            this.template = tmpl(template);
        }, this);

        $.get("/js/templates/" + name + ".html", callback);

    },

    close: function () {

        this.$suggestionList.addClass("hide");
        this.tracking('Close', 'Clicked-Off');


        // Reset our list selection index
        this.model.set("currentIndex", null);

    },

    open: function () {

        this.$suggestionList.removeClass("hide");
        this.tracking('Open', 'Clicked-On');

    },

    preventCloseHandler: function (e) {

        e.stopPropagation();

    },

    directionSelectionHandler: function (keyCode) {

        var currentIndex = this.model.get("currentIndex"),
            incr = keyCode === 40 ? 1 : -1,
            newIndex = currentIndex + incr,
            choicesLen = this.$choices.length - 1,
            isOutOfRange = newIndex > choicesLen || newIndex < 0;

        // If index is out of range set it either to the first or last choice
        if (isOutOfRange) {
            newIndex = newIndex < 0 ? choicesLen : 0;
        }

        // Remove previous selected
        // class on li's
        this.$choices
            .removeClass("is-selected");

        this.$choices
            .eq(newIndex)
            .addClass("is-selected");

        // Store our index
        this.model.set("currentIndex", newIndex);


    },


    enterHandler: function (e) {

        var currentIndex = this.model.get("currentIndex");

        if (currentIndex !== 0) {

            this.tracking('Enter', 'Selected-Choice');

            window.location = this.$choices.eq(currentIndex).find("a").attr('href');

        }

    },

    keyDownHandler: function (e) {

        var keyCode = e.which,
            isArrowKeys = keyCode === 40 || keyCode === 38;

        if (!isArrowKeys) {
            return;
        }

        e.preventDefault();

    },

    keyUpHandler: function (e) {

        var $input = $(e.currentTarget),
            query = $input.val(),
            keyCode = e.which;

        switch (keyCode) {
        case 40:
        case 38:
            this.directionSelectionHandler(keyCode);
            this.tracking('Keyboard navigate', 'Selected-Choice');
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
        case 13:
            this.enterHandler(e);
            break;
        default:
            this.model.set("query", query);
        }
    },

    choiceClickHandler: function (e) {

        this.tracking('Click', 'Selected-Choice');

        e.stopPropagation();

    },

    render: function () {

        this.$suggestionList
            .html(this.template(_.pick(this.model.attributes, "ProductSuggestions", "FilterSuggestions")));

        // Store our list of choices but also add our already cached input to that collection
        this.$choices = this.$suggestionList.find(".autocomplete__choice", this.$el).add(this.$input);

        this.open();

    },

    events: {

        "keyup input": "keyUpHandler",
        "keydown input": "keyDownHandler",
        "click .autocomplete__choice": "choiceClickHandler",
        "click": "preventCloseHandler"

    },

    bindings: function () {

        this.listenTo(this.model, "sync", this.render);
        $(document).on('click', _.bind(this.close, this));

    },

    initialize: function () {

        this.fetchTemplate("suggestions");
        this.$suggestionList = this.$el.find(".autocomplete");
        this.$input = this.$el.find("input");
        this.bindings();

    }
});


context.Views = context.Views || {};
context.Views.SuggestiveSearch = SuggestiveSearch;

}(Backbone, _, =|| {}));
```

Let me know if I need to include anymore information. Thank you in advance!

Comment: [I was able to reproduce this behavior on Amazon](http://i.imgur.com/7bFyWgJ.png)

Comment: Yes but if you use your keyboard keys to scroll up to the one selected  with the mouse they join to become one selection again. On mine it will keep showing two different selections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your JSFiddle doesn't produce the behavior, it's not easy for me to write code that solves your problem, but I can give you advice that might help you do it yourself.

The way I recommend solving this issue is by removing the `.hover` highlighting in your CSS and implementing a function that adds the class `is-selected` to an object when it is being hovered over and removing the class from all other elements. That way it will be compatible with your current `directionSelectionHandler:`